# set model value using array in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS framework.

I have a text box to enter an amount and a drop down to select a type.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.amount"/>
<select ng-model="user.rateType"> 
  <option> rate </option>
  <option> unrate</option>
</select>
<input type="text" ng-model="user.assignVal"/>
```

Here is my controller

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.Main = [
    { id: "1", hval: 1000, lval: 5000, type: "rate", cal: "20" },
    { id: "2", hval: 6000, lval: 10000, type: "rate", cal: "50" },
    { id: "3", hval: 1000, lval: 5000, type: "unrate", cal: "100" },
    { id: "4", hval: 6000, lval: 10000, type: "unrate", cal: "100" },
  ];
  console.log($scope.user.assignVal);
});
```

The user enter an amount in the text-box and select the rate type.
I need to find the element fulfilling the following conditions :

- the user selected type matches item `type`
- the amount entered by the user is in the range delimited by `hval` and`lval`

For example,

- User enters 1100 as amount and select `rate` type, `cal` equals 20
- User enters 6500 as amount and select `rate` type, `cal` equals 50
- User enters 1100 as amount and select `unrate` type, `cal` equals 100

How can I achieve this ?

get request

```
$scope.loadShareSetting = function (){
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('JWT_TOKEN')},
        url: appConfig.apiUrl + "/residence-settings",
    }).then(function (response) {  
     $scope.residenceSetting = response.data;
    }, function (response) {

    });

}
```

Comment: this get request response is very similar to your array. how i assign it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code to achieve this

```js
angular.module("myApp", []);
angular
  .module("myApp")
  .controller("myController", [
    "$scope",
    "myService",
    function ($scope, myService) {
      $scope.getCalForAmount = function () {
        var result = myService.getCalForAmount($scope.amount, $scope.type);
        if (result !== -1) {
          $scope.calForAmount = result.cal;
        } else {
          $scope.calForAmount = ""; // no matching cal, empty field
        }
      };
    },
  ])
  .service("myService", function () {
    var items = [
      { id: "1", hval: 1000, lval: 5000, type: "rate", cal: "20" },
      { id: "2", hval: 6000, lval: 10000, type: "rate", cal: "50" },
      { id: "3", hval: 1000, lval: 5000, type: "unrate", cal: "100" },
      { id: "4", hval: 6000, lval: 10000, type: "unrate", cal: "100" },
    ];
    return {
      getCalForAmount: function (amount, type) {
        var result = items.find(function (item) {
          return (
            /^[0-9]*$/.test(amount) && // amount must be an number
            type === item.type && // type must match
            amount >= item.hval && // amount is in the range delimited by hval
            amount <= item.lval // and lval
          );
        });
        return result || -1;
      },
    };
  });
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}

label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <label>
        <span>Amount</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="amount" ng-change="getCalForAmount()" />
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Type</span>
        <select ng-model="type" ng-change="getCalForAmount()">
          <option>rate</option>
          <option>unrate</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Cal for amount and type</span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="calForAmount" readonly />
      </label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

Checkout [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EQiQ22Kb65Jvfa2A?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1) on Plunker to understand how to load items using http request

Comment: Thanks lot Stephane. I will try this to my actual code. seems to be ok :)

Comment: what happen from below code,
 return result || -1;    ?

Comment: Dear friend my actual data comes from get request. ' var items' array should replace from the get request data. how i do it. i added get request to the question. pls check

Comment: result is returned as a negative number when no item matches the val range and type combination. In this case we do nothing

Comment: I added another demo on Plunker to understand how to load items using http request.